# Nest my quote spans

Tags: php, html

Okay so I have a quote design, and it looks like this:

```
<div id="post_IDHERE">
    <span class="quote">
        <span class="quote_author">An author:</span><br>
        <span class="quote_text">Some text quoted</span>
    </span>
    Some comment on the quote.
</div>
```

My PHP code turning [quote] tags into posted ^ quote design.

```
$data['comment'] = preg_replace("/\[quote=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/", "<span class='quote'><span class='quote_author'>Skriven av $1:</span><br><span class='quote_text'>\"$2\"</span></span><br><br>", $data['comment']);
```

And I have two problems. One is with my quote JS function, but I'll start with my PHP (?) problem.

Basically if $data['comment'] contains:

```
[quote=test]test[/quote]
test quote
```

It'll post:

[image: blabla]

But posting:

```
[quote=test][quote=test]test1[/quote]test2[/quote]
test3
```

Posts:

[image: lalala]

So I assume my regex isn't doing as I want?

Here's a JSfiddle showing nested comments:
http://jsfiddle.net/n74djvq2/7/

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is only looking for `[quote=*] * [/quote]` pattern, so it ends at the first `[/quote]` it sees.

If you really need the feature of nested quotes, you should look for recursive regex pattern, not just the simple version.

Or if you find it difficult, use a function maybe instead of regex.

Comment: How would I do it recursviely?